# Extract word timings from MP3 audio file

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I want to capture audio timings for each word in the audio.

For example, "Introduction Hi Bangalore" consider this is one mp3file(page1.mp3), from that how can extract each word starting time.
i.e., The starting time of "Introduction", "Hi", "Bangalore".
If it is possible?, Possible means, how can i do?
If any software available?.

I  have tried to extract timing using system.speech API using bookmark-reach event but it not as accurate as I want.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.  Are you going from audio to text, or text to audio?

Comment: i want to convert text to audio and then play that audio and highlight words in sync with audio.

Comment: Have you tried the [PhonemeReached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.phonemereached.aspx) event instead?

Comment: System.Speech doesn't generate MP3 files by default, which is why I was confused.  Showing your code would help immensely.

Comment: This problem is now solved. I have used "SpeeckProgress" event to capture word timing. It is working fine on Windows server 2012.

Comment: @PratikPatel I am looking for the same solution, can you share your code or guide how did you achieve it? I am using [Pageflip5](http://pageflip-books.com/) Flipbook and [Read Along](https://github.com/westonruter/html5-audio-read-along)